# When adding Google Analytics 4 support to a site that already has Universal Analytics, do I need both analytics.js and gtag.js, or is gtag.js enough?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a website that is running the Universal Analytics (UA) version of Google Analytics. I would like to add support for Google Analytics 4.

The documentation for adding Google Analytics 4 support asks me to add a `gtag.js` script to my web pages. If I want to continue using UA, do I need to use both `analytics.js` and `gtag.js`, or can I just replace the `analytics.js` tag with `gtag.js` because it will be enough to supply data to both UA and GA4?

Answer (score 1):

In [this Google documentation page about adding the `gtag.js` tag](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165), under the "if the setup wizard did not use your existing tagging" section, under the "add your tag directly to your web pages" accordion, Google says:

> Don't remove the old analytics.js tag; it will continue to collect data for your Universal Analytics property. The gtag.js tag that you're adding will collect data for your new Google Analytics 4 property.

So the answer is that **both tags are needed**.

Comment: While drafting this question, I came across the answer buried in the documentation. I decided to post this Q&A anyways so that other people might have an easier time of finding the answer than I did.